# Получить данные поиска?

Tags: java, android, search

Разбираюсь с поиском в android.
В приложении получается создано 2 активити, одна основная, другая для поиска.
В фрагменте, прикрепленном к основой активити, вызываю метод getActivity().onSearchRequested(), в поисковой активити отлавливаю запрос и отображаю результат в Recycler. Как мне теперь вернуть выбранный элемент recycler в фрагмент откуда начался поиск, если я не вызывал startActivityForResult()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше всего таки стартовать активити через startActivityForResult(), но, раз по к-л причине вам нельзя так делать, то задайте первой активити в манифесте `launch_mode="singleTop"` и запускайте её после выбора вместе с завершением активити с поиском. При этом в `Intent` поместите нужные данные. По идее у первой активити вызовется `onNewIntent()` и вы сможете там вытащить переданные данные и обновить инфу на экране..

---

Судя по [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5958543/3212712) вам надо и базовую активити прописать как активити для поиска в манифесте. После этого вызывать из неё настоящую поисковую активити через `startActivityForResult()` и далее действовать как обычно с возвращением результата через `setResult()`

Comment: Ну он получается сам стартует активити, указанную в манифесте.
` <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".ui.activity.SearchActivity" />`
Получается можно текущее активите сделать поисковым и установить этот флаг, зачем тогда нужно второе?

Comment: @shagi, видимо вы собираетесь использовать поисковую активити немного не так, как планировали её создатели. Вариант для вас дописал в ответ

Comment: Это первое мое знакомство с поисковой активити. В чем тогда основная идея поисковой активности? просто для отображения найденной информации? Просто идея, вроде, простая: ты ищешь что-то с помощью поиска - когда находишь то, что хотел, возвращаешь себе и используешь...

Comment: @shagi, я сам с ней дела никогда не имел и для чего она нужна - без понятия)